# remote sql server backup in local drive

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i wan to backup remote server in local machine

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

Use UNC Path

```
Backup database your_db to disk='\\your_sys_name\drive_name\file_name'
```

Answer (score 2):

As Madhivanan states, you could try to run a backup on the remote server, that backups to a local network share. Requirements are:

1. The SQL Server Service must run under a domain level account
2. The SQL Server Service must have FULL CONTROL access to the network share
3. The UNC network path ( `\\SERVER\SHARENAME` ) should be used, no mapped drive letters

For more information see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555128